# Accepting any https certificate

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, https, axis

I have a Spring Boot application that needs to consume a SOAP Web Service. This SOAP service only accepts HTTPS connections and uses an autogenerated certificate because is a testing enviroment. I don't want to install this certificate in my trust store.

Is there a way to configure my Spring Boot application to accept any invalid certificate?

I'm using axis library to consume this SOAP web service.

Comment: How are you connecting to the SOAP Web Service? With RestTemplate? With some SOAP library?

Comment: @DavidConrad I am using `org.apache.axis.soap.SoapConnectionImpl`